# Two Servers one Domain - What about DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a website mywebsite.com/forum

If you type mywebsite.com in your browser, you will be redirected to mywebsite.com/forum through a script.

Now, I want to have a blog on the main page mywebsite.com and I want to host it on a different Server, with an different IP Address.

How do I have to set up this configuration with DNS Records? I don't want to use subdomains.

Thank you

Comment: Use `example.com` and `forum.example.com` instead.

Comment: It is a relatively large forum with many backlinks now. I don't want do any changes which could influence SEO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this with purely DNS, since it's just for finding hosts - it can't instruct clients on what to do within the HTTP protocol.

The most likely approach you'll want to use with this will be a "reverse proxy" configuration, where the traffic is sent to specific servers or services depending on criteria (like the request address), allowing you to serve different applications under the same apparent host without redirecting to a different hostname for different applications.

Comment: It seems to be much more complicated than I thought. I was afraid of... My idea was to separate them for security and maintenance reasons. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The DNS server knows nothing about url, it only gets domain name.
You have to use a subdomain or another domain.